# $digest already in progress error - with custom directive - not fixed by $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive datepicker that uses `scope.apply` and works well. I cut out most of it to avoid cluttering the question, here is a simple version

```
appAdmin.directive("datepickerPss", ["$compile", "$parse", function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {                   
            $element.datepicker($scope.options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ev.date);
                });
            });
}
}]);
```

I have the custom datepicker in a modal, I simply want to initialize the value so in my controller I did the following at the top and had the "$digest already in progress" error

```
$scope.sDate = Date.now();
```

So reading up on this issue and the scope apply I changed it to the following in my controller

```
$timeout(function() {
        $scope.sDate = Date.now();
    });
```

However I still get the $digest in progress error. I'm not sure where to go from here. All the posts I have read have had their issues resolved by using $timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$scope.$apply` and just use `$timeout` instead.

```
$element.datepicker($scope.options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
    $timeout(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ev.date);
    }, 0);
});
```

`$scope.$apply` starts a new $digest cycle on $rootScope, so calling it inside of your directive starts another $digest cycle while one is already occurring.  By wrapping your call in $timeout, it'll wait until the previous $digest cycle finishes before applying your changes.

In addition, if you are trying to initialize a value AFTER you've already bound bound your change event in your directive, you could run into issues since the directive's digest cycle might still be in progress while your controller is being parsed and executed.

Comment: I tried that but then the value ends up undefined when I use it later is the controller.  `$scope.save = function () {
        $log.info($scope.sDate);} ` plops an "undefined" in the console.

Comment: It seems like you're applying it incorrectly.  It doesn't need a timeout in your controller, it needs it in your directive.  In addition, why wouldn't you set the default in your directive instead of in your controller (particularly in the on change event, which means that you're updating a currently getting-updated value)?  It seems like you're mixed-bag approach is what's causing the real problem.

Comment: The datepicker directive is used many places and I have not needed it initialize the value until now, so I'd like to keep it generic. It seemed to be the simplest way to me. 
I did put the timeout in the directive but it caused the value to be undefined, I'll try to make a simple plunkr to recreate it.